# Reduce length and/or dry out assignment statement that occurs based on presence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Within a class method I have the following line:

```
self.some_hash[:some_key] = change_it(self.some_hash[:some_key]) if self.some_hash[:some_key].present?
```

It works, but it is a long statement, mostly because I am repeating `self.some_hash[:some_key]` three times within the assignment statement.

Is there some ruby syntactic sugar for this where I can shorten this line of code?  Maybe by doing some syntactic sugar to reduce repeating `self.some_hash[:some_key]` three times, or perhaps another technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular line could not be rewritten shortly (at least I do not see any reasonable way to do it,) mostly because the whole design is not quite rubyish.

1. Use inplace change instead of reassignment. `a = change_it(a)` is bad, `a.change_it` is good (whenever possible and it turns out it is possible nearly always.)
2. `a.present?` in most cases is a superfluous check. Do you really need it? Won’t plain old good ruby `if a` suffice?

With refactoring above taken into consideration, the codepiece above would become:

*with simple check for `nil or false`:*

```
self.some_hash[:some_key] &&= change_it self.some_hash[:some_key]
```

*with both changes:*

```
self.some_hash[:some_key].tap { |v| v.change_it if v }
```

I understand that is not an exact answer on your question, but I hope it might help.

**UPD** As noted by @WandMaker, `self` looks suspiciously superfluous here as well.

Comment: How you managed to make `change_it` a method of `v` in your example with `tap` - not sure that code works - I am just trying to understand

Comment: @mudasobwa `&&=` checks to see if the left side evaluates to true, correct?  If it does, then it executes the right side?

Comment: To clarify, `&&=` only does the assignment if _not_ nil and _not_ false

Comment: To `truthy`, in other words in it neither `false` nor `nil`. `tap` just taps the receiver, as soon as the hint 1. above is applied, hash values have `change_it` method on them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple alternative

```
hash[:key] &&= change_it(hash[:key])
```

but it only checks for `nil` and it will not set the value again if it was false, which may or may not be what you want. While `.present?` not only checks for nil but also when given a string or array, if is non-empty.

Alternatively, Why not just define a method?

E.g.

```
def change_if_present(hash, key)
  hash[key] = change_it(hash[key]) if hash[key].present? 
end
```

or if you have to do the same for a bunch of keys, you could just write

```
[:key_a, :key_b, ...].each do |key|
   hash[key] = change_it(hash[:key]) if hash[:key].present? 
end
```

And then you could even wrap that in a method

```
def change_values_if_key_present(hash, keys)
  keys.each do |key|
    hash[key] = change_it(hash[key]) if hash[key].present? 
  end
end
```

Of course this is assuming the change is the same for all keys.